# Unable to add the action button based on checkbox in ag-grid

Tags: html, reactjs, ag-grid

I want to add the checkbox in each row. Once the checkbox is selected then particular row edit or delete button will visible. Please find the code snippet. I am using ag-grid library. Any help will appreciated.

```
function actionCellRenderer(params) {
  let eGui;
  let editingCells = params.api.getEditingCells();
  let isCurrentRowEditing = editingCells.some((cell) => {
    return cell.rowIndex === params.node.rowIndex;
  });

  if (isCurrentRowEditing) {
    eGui = (
      <div>
        <button class="action-button update" data-action="update">
          {" "}
          update{" "}
        </button>

        <button className="action-button cancel" data-action="cancel">
          {" "}
          cancel{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    eGui = (
      <div>
        <button className="action-button edit" data-action="edit">
          {" "}
          edit{" "}
        </button>
        <button className="action-button delete" data-action="delete">
          {" "}
          delete{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return eGui;
}
```

// adding action column

```
const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
        {
          field: "athlete",
          cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
          cellEditorParams: {
            values: ["Porsche", "Toyota", "Ford", "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"],
          },
        },
        { field: "age" },
        {
          headerName: "",
          cellRenderer: actionCellRenderer,
          editable: false,
          colId: "action",
        },
      ]);
```

Comment: On the checkbox change event, you have to re-render cells. Another way you can do this is by creating a custom checkbox component that will toggle the visibility of only targeted buttons.

Comment: @Basit How checkbox will decide in that row Button will visible?

Comment: you can target that button using the closest() & find() methods of jQuery, or you can use javascript to do that.